# popen on process with no output

Tags: c++, popen

I have this code, I try to open a process with popen, get its output and keep for later, after every char read from proc I verify if a certain amount of time has passed and if true I give up and close the process. 
The problem is that if the process for some reason has no output at all but is open and running I will never have a chance to verify my timeout so the loop will never exit. 
Any suggestion how this can be solved ?

```
  char buffer[1024];

  FILE *proc;  //we need a file descriptor for the process
  proc = popen(commandLine.c_str(),"r");  // We never pipe data into spawned processes so second parameter is always "r"
  if (!proc)
      return -1;  //if it does not work we return right away
  std::time_t startTime = std::time(NULL);
  while (!feof(proc))
  {
      if (fgets(buffer, 1, proc) != NULL) //read until there is something to read
      {
          output->append(buffer);
          std::time_t currTime = std::time(NULL);
          int seconds = std::difftime(currTime,startTime);
          if (seconds >= timeout) break;
      }
      else
          break;
  }
  int closeFd  = pclose(proc);
  int exitCode = WEXITSTATUS(closeFd);
  return exitCode;
```

Comment: On which OS are you running? Under linux you may use the file descriptor encapsulated in the `proc` `FILE*` structure with a `poll()` or `select()` loop to enable non blocking `read()`.

Comment: Yes it is linux, gonna try that right away